# How can i find the solution of this NP-hard optimization problem?

Tags: integer-programming, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming

I have an NP-Hard optimization problem of the form:

\begin{align}
  & \min {{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}{{{a}_{i}}}}_{{}}} \\ 
 & s.t{{.}\:\:\:\:_{{}}}{{_{{}}}_{{}}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}{{{a}_{i}}{{a}_{i+k}}}>0\:\: \: \:{{,}_{{}}}{{_{{}}}_{{}}}\forall k=0,1,\ldots ,M-1 \\ 
 & \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:{{a}_{i}}\in \left\{ 0,1 \right\}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:{{,}_{{}}}i=1,\ldots ,M. \\ 
\end{align}

How can I found any optimum or sub-optimum solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can linearize the quadratic constraint by introducing a binary variable $b_{i,k}$ to represent the product $a_i a_{i+k}$.  The new constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_i b_{i,k} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $k$}\\
b_{i,k} &\le a_i &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$}\\
b_{i,k} &\le a_{i+k} &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$}
\end{align}

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, Thanks for your response. why do you add $i≤k$? Do you have a suggestion for any algorithms for solving your simplified proposed problem?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. You can use an integer linear programming solver to solve the linearized formulation.